# Double Integral of 1/(y-x) diverges or not?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, expected-value

I was wondering if one were to integrate
$$\int_0^{b_2}\int_0^{b_1} \frac{1}{y-x} \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y $$
where $b_2\geq b_1$ and both are strictly positive, would it diverge or not? I feel a bit uncomfortable with this because we know $\frac{1}{x}$ is divergent when we integrate across 0 but that does not seem to be the case here. Perhaps we first integrate with respect to $x$ to get
$$\int_0^{b_2} ln(y)-ln|y-b_1|\ \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^{b_2}ln(y)\ \mathrm{d}y - \int_0^{b_2}\ln|y-b_1|\ \mathrm{d}y.$$
The second term can be split into two
$$\int_0^{b_1} \ln(b_1-y) \mathrm{d}y + \int_{b_1}^{b_2}\ln(y-b_1)\mathrm{d}y.$$
So now we have
$$\int_0^{b_2}ln(y)\ \mathrm{d}y - \int_0^{b_1} \ln(b_1-y)\ \mathrm{d}y - \int_{b_1}^{b_2}\ln(y-b_1)\ \mathrm{d}y$$
and thus
$$
y\ln(y)-y\Big|_0^{b_2} - (y-b_1)(\ln(b_1-y)-1)\Big|_0^{b_1} - (y-b_1)(\ln(y-b_1)-1)\Big|_{b_1}^{b_2} 
$$
But we know that $\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=0$, so we can evaluate this to
$$b_2(\ln(b_2)-1) - (b_1)(\ln(b_1)-1) - (b_2-b_1)(\ln(b_2-b_1)-1).$$
Some terms cancel and we can get rid of the $-1$'s to get:
$$b_2\ln(b_2)-b_1\ln(b_1)-(b_2-b_1)\ln(b_2-b_1).$$
But I'm not quite sure if this is all rigorous and when I chugged the double integral into Wolfram Alpha, it tells me that it diverges, but if it in fact does, can somebody explain to me where I went wrong on here? Would changing the integral into something like 
$$\int_c^{b_2}\int_c^{b_1} \frac{1}{y-x} \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y $$
make it converge because we avoid the critical point of $0$?

This question came up when I was trying to find $\mathbb{E}[1/(Y-X)]$ where $Y\sim \textrm{Unif}\ [0,b_2]$ and $X\sim \textrm{Unif}\ [0,b_1]$ uniform distributions. If there's a better method to find that instead please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know anything else about $b_1$ and $b_2$?

Comment: we know $b_2\geq b_1$ and that they are both positive, edited that in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer has flaws in the first part. If you want to say
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{b_2}\int_0^{b_1} \frac{1}{y-x} \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y =
\int_0^{b_2} ln(y)-ln|y-b_1|\ \mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
$y$ should lie outside of $[0, b_1]$ since $1/(y-x)$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on the direction. Since there always exists some $y\in[0,b_2]$ such that $y\in[0,b_1]$, this integral cannot be defined. Because of this, the integral you initially propose cannot be defined.

Comment: Just to clarify, you imply that because $[0,b_1]\subseteq[0,b_2]$, for certain values of $y$ we cannot integrate the function $1/(y-x)$ by simply holding $y$ as a constant?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that changing the integral to from $c$ to $b_1$ and $c$ to $b_2$ would not help with this problem at all as it still runs into the same issue?

Comment: @alpha_beta_gamma Oh, no, regardless of the values of $b_1$ and $b_2$, it will be problematic.. because, for example, even if $b_1=2$ and $b_2=1$, for $y=0.5$, the inner integral cannot be defined. So, as long as, $b_1>0$ and $b_2>0$, this integral cannot be defined.

Comment: @alpha_beta_gamma And yes, to your second question. changing to $c$ to $b_1$ and $c$ to $b_2$ wouldn't change the situation. However, if the two integration intervals does NOT overlap, your integral can be defined and the value would be, of course, finite!

Comment: Okay, thank you! As a final question, if we were to have the integral be $x$ from $0$ to $b_1$ and $y$ from $b_1$ to $b_2$, would this work? I have a feeling it wouldn't because $y$ still takes $b_1$ as a value so the regions of integral have to be completely disjoint, but please let me know, thank you!

Comment: @alpha_beta_gamma You're very right! I'm glad that now you have perfect understanding of the nature of your math problem!